# duplicate php classes inside a file

Tags: php, class, require-once

I need to find a way to skip require_once error in case 2 php classes, with same name, are called in a file.
I have 2 files a.php and b.php and each of them have class A declared inside.
Inside index.php I first include a.php file which has class A declared. Also inside index.php I must include c.php, which inside it has require_once b.php and for this reason I get duplicate classname error and the script is stopped.
Can I find a workaround for this?
Thanks for your reply

---

Let me explain it better. 
Is about Joomla and I build a plugin to overwrite a component models and views. I included my models and views classes in the plugin and Joomla uses them instead of the original component models and views classes. 
The problem appears when a component module is including the component original models and views classes with require_once.
Since my plugin is not using the original models classes, so the file where the original models classes are, is not included inside Joomla, the module require_one is able to include the component model classes, and those classes has the same name as my plugin ones.
I can only change my plugin code and classes and not component classes, the second ones.

Comment: Don't have two classes by the same name. Period.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to find a way to skip require_once error in case 2 php classes, with same name, are called in a file.

No you don't. You shouldn't have 2 classes in the same file. Uhhhmm lemme rephrase that. You cannot have two classes with the same name (unless namespaced). But seriously you shouldn't have two classes in 1 file.

> I have 2 files a.php and b.php and each of them have class A declared inside.

I guess (/ hope) they are not the same classes because that would violate (rape) the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

> Can I find a workaround for this?

Don't copy the same class. If both classes are different namespace it. Either the new way with real namespaces or the old way:

```
namespace Lib\Your\Namespace;
```

or

```
class Lib_Your_Namespace
```

Comment: I know I must not have 2 classes with the same name, but I can't change the code of b.php or remove it...hoping there's a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the require call in

```
if(!class_exists('your_class_name')) {
     require_once('file_name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the namespace - this is what you need